# Ground Power KVA when on stand

Tags: electrical-system

How much power from a GPU would a jet, say a Boeing 737, require when boarding passengers or just sat idle on the air bridge?

I’m guessing the Aircraft would only consume the full 90kVA ground power rating when starting the aircraft’s APU?

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: From the amount of noise they make, I'd say tons of power!  Nothing more irritating than the high pitched whine of an APU or GPU.  Except maybe neighborhood leaf blowers running for hours on end...

Comment: Depends, are they using air conditioning, and how much? This is the main power consumption on the ground, other than starting; some airports have ground conditioned air. I'd be surprised by more than 10-20kVA in average conditions